# Not able to access microphone on web app running on digitalocean droplet inside a docker container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, digital-ocean

I'm building a sort of voice recorder app. I m using MediaRecorder for that. the app is working perfectly on my local machine . However when I deploy the app to digitalocean droplet and run it inside a docker container, I m not able to access microphone and I m getting permission denied.

code snippet

```
const permission = await navigator.permissions.query({
      name: "microphone",
    });
    console.log({ permission });

    if (permission.state !== "granted") {
      setError("Microphone permission denied");
      return;
    }

    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    audioStreamRef.current = stream;
```

Expected behavior is the browser ask for microphone permission when the record button is clicked, however is not working after deploying to digitalocean